# Arules get 0 rules for apriori algorithm, but why?

Tags: r, unique, rules, apriori, arules

I have data like this [data redundant](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x5ttafriuno3uyn/dataredundan.png?dl=0). So, i want to remove the redundant item, by unique code, then i have got this data like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rapvsrngmjkp0zc/Untitled.png?dl=0). Then i try to get rules by arules.

```
library(arules)
library(qpcR)
data<- read.csv("Book1.csv", header=TRUE)
b<-sapply(1:ncol(data), function(x) unique(data[,x]))
b<-lapply(b,as.data.frame)
a<-list()
databaru<-do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, lapply(b, as.vector))
databaru[]<-lapply(databaru,as.factor)
colnames(databaru)<-colnames(data)
rules<-apriori(databaru, parameter=list(supp=0.0016, conf=0.1))
inspect(rules)
```

Then when i try running it, I got 0 rules, i am sure before i removed he redundant item each column, i got many rules, but, when i try run the code, and delete the code for removing redundant item, i got 0 rule too.. (redundant : i use code "unique")
Then i try the support and confidence give the lower value, but i still didnt get it.

```
Apriori

Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport support minlen maxlen target   ext
        0.1    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE  0.0016      1     10  rules FALSE

Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 4 

set item appearances ...[0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[34440 item(s), 2561 transaction(s)] done [0.02s].
sorting and recoding items ... [0 item(s)] done [0.00s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.00s].
checking subsets of size 1 done [0.00s].
writing ... [0 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.00s].
```

What should i do? what's wrong? what's happen? Thank you so much for helping

Comment: I guess at least your `as.factor` is a guilty step (if not other ones). For each column, codes will be encoded with different values.  I would either precise possible levels in the call or - simpler - keep raw values.

Comment: I can't do running arules if i have not changed it to factor. So, what should I do? because when i delete it, it give error, because i should discretize it. 
But how? because my data are integer, but they are not for cotinous variable, they are ID.

Comment: You may begin to first retrieve all unique values, for instance with `levels <- unique(unlist(databaru))` and use this vector when creating factor: `lapply(databaru, as.factor, levels=levels)`  (not tested as you don't provide some data to test)

Answer (score 0):

Association rule mining needs (binary) items and not numeric (continuous) variables. You need to discretize each numeric variable in your data. See `? discretize` in package `arules`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to lower the support and confidence values even *further*.

`library( tidyverse )`

`view_transactions %>% 
  apriori( parameter = list( maxlen = 100, supp = 0, conf = .01), control = list( verbose = T))`

...especially if the number of rows you are processing is very high - because that would affect the support.

One more thing: did you remember to FIRST convert your data frame to transactions?

`view_transactions <- your_data_frame %>%`
`# head(n = 1000) %>%`
`# filter( !is.na( filterValue )) %>%`
`filter( ! filterValue %in% commonValues ) %>%`
`select( filterName, filterValue ) %>%`
`mutate_all( as.factor ) %>%`
`as( "transactions" )`